# Why do I not need to reenter credentials after logging out of my next.js app (next-auth-example) and cognito?

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

I connected the [next-auth-example](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example) with AWS Cognito.

I've read some posts and questions that it is intended by next-auth that I am not really logged out from Cognito after hitting the logout-button. In this case it is expected, that after clicking the login-button, I am logged in again without entering credentials again.

So I tried for a complete logout:

1. logging out in the app
2. clearing cookies
3. logging out user in Cognito

Still I can login again without needing to enter my credentials again. I suppose that this is not intended and probably some kind of misconfiguration in my side?